# How to compare date in sqlite (Android)

Tags: android, sqlite, date, datetime

i know there might be alot of questions about this out here but none meets my usecase. so here i go.

i'm saving datetime to my sqlite in this format: 2016-12-12 08:00:40;
That is year-month-day hours-mins-secs. This works splendid.

Now i want to get the results where date equals a date is chose of a datepicker. It selects in same format but i don't get the desired results.

```
 SELECT * FROM table WHERE thedate = 2016-12-12 00:00:00;
```

It only works where 2016-12-12 08:00:40 = 2016-12-12 08:00:40;

So how do i get the results when date = date, i want to ignore the timestamp. if the date is the same, show it.

In my database, i've got columns with thedates

```
2016-12-11 03:00:40;
2016-12-12 03:00:40;
2016-12-12 04:00:40;
2016-12-12 06:00:40;
```

i should be able to get all the 2016-12-12 results. Any help is appreciated. I've also tried using strftime function in my query. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To extract the date from a complete timestamp, use the [date() function](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_datefunc.html):

```
SELECT ... WHERE date(thedate) = '2016-12-12';
```